# riverpod AsyncValue is always 'loading', StreamProvider not working

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a class that creates a `StreamController` of some object `T`, and once listened to, it connects to an external event and calls `StreamController.add`.

```
class ProtoReceiveMessageChannel<T extends GeneratedMessage> {
  /// The logical channel on which communication happens, not null.
  final String name;
  final BinaryMessenger _binaryMessenger = ServicesBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger;
  final ProtoDecoder<T> _receiveCodec;
  late StreamController<T> _streamController;

  ProtoReceiveMessageChannel(this.name, this._receiveCodec) {
    _streamController = StreamController<T>.broadcast(onListen: _onListen);

    _binaryMessenger.setMessageHandler(name, onMessage);
  }
  void _onListen() {
    _binaryMessenger.setMessageHandler(name, onMessage);
  }

  Stream<T> get messageStream {
    return _streamController.stream;
  }

  Future<ByteData?>? onMessage(ByteData? message) {
    var decodedMsg = _receiveCodec.decodeMessage(message);

    if (decodedMsg != null) {
      _streamController.add(decodedMsg);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Using debug printing, I can clearly see that the `StreamController` is listened to (`_onListen` is called) and that the external event does add elements to the `StreamController`.

However, when trying to use riverpod `StreamProvider`, I don't receive any events from the stream (`AsyncValue` is always in loading state).

Here is my provider:

```
final appWindowStateProvider = StreamProvider<AppWindowState>((ref) {
  final appWindowStateStream = ProtoReceiveMessageChannel<AppWindowState>(
      'u/AppWindowState', ProtoDecoder<AppWindowState>((bytes) => AppWindowState.fromBuffer(bytes)));

  return appWindowStateStream.messageStream;
});
```

And here is my widget which always "loading":

```
class MinimizeMaximizeButton extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MinimizeMaximizeButton({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    var appWindowStateAsync = ref.watch(appWindowStateProvider);

    return appWindowStateAsync.when(
      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      error: (error, stackTrace) => Text(error.toString()),
      data: (appWindowState) => ActionButton(
        onTap: () => appWindowState.isMaximized
            ? ref.read(platfromServiceProvider).restoreWindow()
            : ref.read(platfromServiceProvider).maximizeWindow(),
        child: Icon(appWindowState.isMaximized ? Icons.filter_none : Icons.rectangle_outlined),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Similar issue.  After updating record, Nav.pop returns to ConsumerWidget, but it never rebuilds.  No stream data about the update, so can't rebuild with new data.